# Modified Union Find Data Structure

Tags: python, data-structures, union-find

connected: takes two arguments s and t and returns true if they are in the same set and false otherwise.

combine: takes two arguments s and t and creates a union of the two sets that contain s and t such that if s is in S and t is in T it removes S and T and replaces it with the union of S and T.

Comment: It is not really clear what your datastructure is. You initialize by making just one list ranging from 0 to n-1?
If you have one list containing just different integer elements you will never see that find(s) == find(t) if s != t